# Random space under first SQL value

Tags: php, css, sql

I am working on a voting system that shows what people have been voting for, showing the names of the Movies. I have never had this problem before and can't find anything about it online.
[image: Problem outlines by red box]

Outlined by the red box is the problem, a random space for the first value that is printed.

Here is the code for the text

```
echo "<br><form method='POST' action='vote.php'>
<font size='5'><center>".$row['moviename']."</center></font>
</center>
```

And here is the code for the votes bar

```
.wrap {
margin-right: 500px;               
margin-left: 500px;             
width: auto;
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: #000000;
padding: 2px;
}    
.bar {
background: orange;
height: 24px;
border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question... If you need any more code please ask.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect your code using Chrome or Firefox developer tools?

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing i did... The code is the same for each title.

Comment: Not the code. The CSS rules to each item!

Comment: Put a fiddle that represents this error!

Comment: Is there a link for this to look at or JSFiddle it so that its musch easier to debug.

Comment: You can try using MySQL's [`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function in your query.

Comment: Your posted code is either missing alot of things, or `html` is broken, ie: no `form` closing tag, `center` tag closing without opening, no `.wrap` class found anywhere

Comment: If there are new line in the Movie names you might have to remove them use preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $row['moviename'] );